# Understanding which method will be invoked

Tags: c++, overloading

A class `Base` has a method `void foo(float a)`. Class `Sub` inherits publicly from `Base` and has a method `void foo(int a)`.

I have `s` an instance of `Sub` (stored in a `Sub*`), and call `s->foo(1.5)`. It's `Sub::foo` that gets executed (with the argument truncated to `1`), rather than `Base::foo`. Why is this?

I would naively expect it to execute the original method defined in `Base`, seeing as the argument is a float. How could I achieve this instead?

Comment: Your question would be better if you included a small code example. I know you described the code but its better have an example.

Comment: `float` values will be implicitely converted to `int` values. Nothing forces to call the base class function.

Answer (score 4):

With

```
struct Base
{
    void foo(float a);
};

struct Sub : Base
{
    void foo(int a); // Hides Base::Foo
};
```

`Sub::foo` hides `Base::foo`,

you have to add `using` to allow both overloads.

```
struct Sub : Base
{
    using Base::foo;
    void foo(int a);
};
```

More details on [using_declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration)

And for your call:

```
Sub s;
s.foo(1.5); // Ambiguous with using, Sub::foo(int) without using.
```

without using, only one overload is considered, so `Sub::foo(int)` is called.

With `using`, both overloads are considered, but neither is a better match than the other, so it is ambiguous.